# Persisting user settings

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-css, settings

I'd like to build a website where users could log in and change the theme and the positions of elements of the website. So basically they can add/remove/move/change color elements on the site. After they save the settings, they come back with the same login and find the site is as they left it.

So my question is: Whats the most practical way to do this? Saving all data to MySQL and loading it back when the visitor logs in? Using PHP to make new PHP files?

If I where to save to MySQL, how do I handle `< > ; ' -` ? Put them all into their own column?

Comment: @Strawberry - relevance?

Comment: @Lix The OP wanted to know the most practical way of achieving the above

Comment: @Strawberry - so your recommendation to someone looking to persist user settings is to "Get a wordpress account"?

Comment: @user3635319 - could you please elaborate what you mean by those characters? `< > ; ' -`

Comment: Save the data in SQL, if you want it "real time movement", then I would advise jQuery (UI). Regarding your web language then any web language whether it be PHP, Python, even JSP I believe could do what you want.

Comment: @Lix: yes, that's actually a good answer. This is a problem solved by existing software. Having the OP write a CMS from scratch when they clearly don't know the first thing about it is just not a good idea.

Comment: @siride - how on earth is that considered enough to be an answer? There is an entire site SE dedicated to wordpress - simply suggesting that you use it is **not an answer at all**. Furthermore - I don't see that comment being very useful to the OP without *any* context and more explanations.

Comment: @Lix: first, there's no valid answer (according to how we do things on SO) that can answer this question, so that point is moot. Second, pointing the user towards Wordpress *is* a good first step. They can come back with specific questions once they get into it. Regardless, Wordpress is the right direction and to say anything else here would be doing the site and the OP a big disservice.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do pretty much the same by writing all settings to my MySQL database, but I just have a few settings for each user and I only save those which are different from the default. Probably you could do the same with cookies, but this would not depend on the user (except you delete those cookies at logout). What I also do is to save the settings when changed via js & php, there is no save button to be clicked.

Comment: Thanks for you time to answer my question.